# Why this asm code not doubling the value the pointer points

Tags: c, assembly, x86, att

I am trying to interface c code with asm.
But it is not working correctly and I am not able to find the problem.

**program.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int *asm_multi(int *ptr);

int main()
{
  int i=10;
  int *p=&i;
  asm_multi(p);
  printf("%d\n",*p);
  return 0;
}
```

**code.asm**

```
.section .text
.global asm_multi
.type asm_multi,@function
asm_multi:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp,%ebp
    movl 8(%ebp),%eax
    movl %eax,%edx
    leal (%edx,%edx,1),%edx
    movl %edx,%eax
    movl %ebp,%esp
    popl %ebp
    ret
```

I am creating the final executable by

```
as code.asm -o code.o
gcc program.c code.o -o  output
./output
```

> The output it prints is :10 whereas I am expecting: 20

What is the problem in the code? Don't consider the efficiency of the program. I have just started asm programming.

I created above code after reading from a more complex example kept at [this link](https://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2008/08/15/calling-an-asm-function-from-c/). This works perfectly.

Comment: Unrelated, if you just started asm programming and know C, spending time pouring over *simple* functions sent through the C compiler with asm-generation turned on (`-S`) at various flavors of optimization (including none) can be *very* informative, and I highly encourage it. This function would be an *excellent* candidate for that technique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should learn to use a debugger as soon as possible. It not only helps you find bugs, but also allows you to exactly see what the cpu is doing at each instruction and you can compare that to your intentions.

Also, comment your code, especially when asking for help, so we can tell you where the instructions don't match your intentions, if you were unable to do so yourself.

Let's comment your code then:

```
asm_multi:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp,%ebp
    movl 8(%ebp),%eax        # fetch first argument, that is p into eax
    movl %eax,%edx           # edx = p too
    leal (%edx,%edx,1),%edx  # edx = eax + edx = 2 * p
    movl %edx,%eax           # eax = edx = 2 * p
    movl %ebp,%esp
    popl %ebp
    ret
```

As you can see, there are two problems:

1. You are doubling the pointer not the value it points to
2. You are not writing it back into memory, just returning it in eax which is then ignored by the C code

A possible fix:

```
asm_multi:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp,%ebp
    movl 8(%ebp),%eax       # fetch p
    shll $1, (%eax)         # double *p by shifting 1 bit to the left
# alternatively
#   movl (%eax), %edx       # fetch *p
#   addl %edx, (%eax)       # add *p to *p, doubling it
    movl %ebp,%esp
    popl %ebp
    ret
```